# jQuery ScrollTop() function animation menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a little problem, I try to use jquery for create animation in my navbar.
My navbar animation it's like this : http://www.vogue.fr/?international 
But my problem it's the animation start only when i'm at the top of page. 
But I need the animation begins when the user scroll up or scroll down from anywhere.

My Jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   if ($(document).scrollTop() < 1) {
    $('nav').addClass('navYolo');
    $('nav').removeClass('navYo');
    $( "ul" ).show();
 } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('navYolo');
    $('nav').addClass('navYo');
    $( "ul" ).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

If someone can help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want the header to be shown an at all times? Or just show on scroll down, but not when scrolling up?

Comment: Thanks for your help too, it's done now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the direction of the scroll and add/remove class of your nav.

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > lastScrollTop){
       $('nav').addClass('hidden');
   } else {
      $('nav').removeClass('hidden');
   }
   lastScrollTop = currentScroll;
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  transition: height 0.3s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease 0s;
}

nav.hidden {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav></nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this, here you can exactly set the scroll values you want to target and you can even set the width of the viewing device, some animations you do not want to do on mobile f.e.
This is the most important part of the code, the rest is in the link.
I have added opacity change and a transform function, sorry for not using native JS for this, its actually rather easy, but short on time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var previousScroll = 0;

$(window).scroll(function(){

var currentScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
 var screenWidth = $( window ).width();


if (currentScroll >= 0 && currentScroll < $(document).height() -    $(window).height() && screenWidth > 800){}
```

Link to the codepen

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/PZQVOR